# How to assert a method is called depending on user input in another class. Python Unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

Given I have two classes in Python.

```
class Interface:
  def user_interface(self):
      my_val = input()
      if my_val == 1:
           datamanager.import_from_file() 
      

class Datamanager:
   def import_from_file(self):
       pass

interface = Interface()
datamanager = Datamanager ()
```

I would like to write a unittest and find out if the method datamanager.import_from_file() was called. The problem is I am either able to patch the input or to assert that the function was called but not both at the same time. So far I have tried the following test within a unittest, but it does not work.

```
class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):

   
    def setUp(self):
        self.test_interface = Interface()

    def tearDown(self):
        print("End Test\n") 

@patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[1])
    def test_func1__should_call_func2(self, mock_input):
        self.test_interface.user_interface()
        self.test_interface.import_from_file = MagicMock()
        self.test_interface.import_from_file.assert_called()

   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You should certainly set up all mocks *before* actually calling `user_interface()`. What is `self.test_interface`, how does `interface` get an instance of `datamanger`?

Comment: Thank you luk2392 for your reply. I edited my orginal post to make my approach clearer. Hope that helps.

Comment: You aren't creating an instance of `Datamanger` at the moment, only defining a second reference `datamanger` to the class. `Interface.user_interface` should not depend on a global reference to a `Datamanger` instance.

Comment: If anything it should be `interface = Interface(Datamanager())`. That way your test can create a Mock and then pass it into `test_interface = Interface(mocked_datamanager)`.

Comment: Thank you luk2302, could you maybe elaborate a little bit on how that would work?